# Replace specific values in a dataframe column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with a column called "Num_of_employees", which has values like 50-100, 200-500 etc. I see a problem with few values in my data. Wherever the employee number should be 1-10, the data has it as 10-Jan. Also, wherever the value should be 11-50, the data has it as Nov-50. How would I rectify this problem using pandas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A clean syntax for this kind of "find and replace" uses a dict, as

```
df.Num_of_employees = df.Num_of_employees.replace({"10-Jan": "1-10",
                                                   "Nov-50": "11-50"})
```

Comment: If you have a large data set, it might be impossible to use replace like this manually.

Comment: @JoeR Right! Is there a way which I can implement on large data?

Comment: I ran this over 100,000,000 rows and finished in a couple of seconds.  IMO, this is your solution.

Comment: What if there are more errors like these? Do we specify each such value in the dictionary?

Comment: @user6461192 yes.  There cannot be very many types.  you can find them all with `df.Num_of_employees.unique()` or `df.Num_of_employees.value_counts()`  create a dictionary with all offending entries and the corresponding corrections.

Comment: @piRSquared Using the above piece of code, I am able to make changes in the df. I can see the output. But when I export the result in a csv, the changes aren't shown. Can you figure out any particular reason for the same?

Comment: you might not be assigning the result back to the column. `df.Num_of_employees.replace({'10-Jan': '1-10', 'Nov-50': '11-50'})` will display the results but you have to capture them with `df.Num_of_employees = df.Num_of_employees.replace({'10-Jan': '1-10', 'Nov-50': '11-50'})`.  You can check before you write your file with `print(df.to_csv())`

Comment: @piRSquared I am doing that. It doesn't work. I have started a separated thread for the same. If you have any comments - Please post it there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294115/changes-in-data-frame-not-reflected-in-csv-output